# Cannot create an array of functions

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create an array of functions so I can later use it to loop through the amount of buttons are displayed on the user interface.

Here is my .hpp snippet:

```
public slots:
   void coin5C();
   void coin10C();
   void coin20C();
   void coin50C();
   void coin1EUR();
   void (connections[5])() = { coin5C, coin10C, coin20C, coin50C, coin1EUR };
```

The last line is supposed to put them all in to an array, but I seem to be getting a error

`Declaration of 'connections' as array of functions`

In my .cpp this is how I want to use my array function (above last line):

```
  for(int i = 0; i < NumButtons; i++) {

       // Error checking
       if(btnNames[i] == "") {
           btnNames[i] = "btnNames " + QString::number(i);
       }

       buttons[i] = new QPushButton(btnNames[i]);
       layout1->addWidget(buttons[i]);

       connect(buttons[i], SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT( connections[i]() ));

   }
```

If I use `void (*connections[5])() = { coin5C, coin10C, coin20C, coin50C, coin1EUR };` I get the error:

```
cannot convert 'MainWindow::coin5C' from type 'void (MainWindow::)()' to type 'void (*)()'
void (*connections[5])() = { coin5C, coin10C, coin20C, coin50C, coin1EUR };
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Helpful Reading: [Pointers to Member Functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members)

Comment: `slots:` is not part of Standard C++, are you using something like QT? (If so then tagging your question as QT would help)

Answer (score 1):

```
void (*connections[5])() = { coin5C, coin10C, coin20C, coin50C, coin1EUR };
```

declares an array of function pointers.  You want an array of *member* function pointers.  Try something like this:

```
void (MainWindow::*connections[5])() = { &MainWindow::coin5C, &MainWindow::coin10C, &MainWindow::coin20C, &MainWindow::coin50C, &MainWindow::coin1EUR };
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides making an array of method pointers you also want to put it inside the class body. This works if you declare your array as `static constexpr`. Look at the example program below. It also defines type `AMethod`, which is just a pointer to method of `A`, to make code a little cleaner.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  typedef void(A::*AMethod)();
  void a(){ std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
  void b(){ std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
  constexpr static AMethod ptrs[2] = {&A::a, &A::b};  
};


int main()
{
  A a;
  (a.*A::ptrs[0])();
  (a.*A::ptrs[1])();
}
```